# Setting up Refresh Schedule in Power BI Service for VSTS Analytics View

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

In VSTS I have created a custom Analytics View for use in Power BI.  Then I went into Power BI and connected to that View using an Organizational Account.  This connected fine from the Power BI client and I was able to build out the report without issues.  In this report I also connect to some On-Premise data and merge things together.

After I finished building the report I published it to the Power BI Service.  Now I can see the report through the web.  Now I need to setup a refresh schedule, so that the information will be updated automatically.  I have setup an On-Premise Gateway Server in the Power BI Service, which connects to my On-Premise data correctly and have also checked off to allow the Gateway to connect to cloud services.

The next step is the credentials in the refresh.  No matter what I try to do and enter credentials in the Power BI service nothing is accepted.  There is 3 choices that I have tried Basic, Key, and OAuth2.

Sorry for the long delay I was away on vacation.

Here is the credential screen
[image]

Once I click on Sign in I get the popup to select my AAD credentials and once I do that it comes back with the failure

Comment: What the username you used if you auth with basic? Please use the alternate credential username (secondary username) and it's password instead.

Comment: I setup alternate credentials in VSTS and then switched the Power credentials to use basic and put in the information, but I'm still getting an error "The provider is not support or due to invalid data source"

Comment: Can you show the screen shot data source for you configured in the gateway?

Comment: Provide the detail code here.

Comment: Added screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic URL is not supported. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/VSTS-odata-refresh-issue/m-p/423899/highlight/true#M45458